# SQL Statement read authorization

Tags: sql-server

I have a database `DB_Customers` in SQL Server, with 3 views: `View_01`, `View_02`, `View_03`

There are also 2 Active Directory groups: `AD_01`, `AD_02`.

- The group `AD_01` should only have read authorization for `view_01` and `view_02`
- Group `AD_02` should only have read authorization for `view_03`

I have done this:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'ARG')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [ARG] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
END

ALTER SCHEMA ARG
    TRANSFER View_01

ALTER SCHEMA ARG
    TRANSFER View_02
```

How can I grant in SQL statement `AD_01` read authorization for `view_01` and `view_02`?

Comment: What do you mean by "read authorisation"? Do you actually mean they need to be able to `SELECT` from it? There is no "READ AUTHORIZATION" [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Ok. That is read permission.

Comment: How can I grant in SQL statement AD_01 read permission to view_01 and view_02?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "read"?

Comment: ReadPermission means that the members of active directory AD_01 can only read the datasets in view_01. They can not insert or change a dataset.
I want to know, how can i in a SQL Statement to Grant this permission.
I hobe this explation can help to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: So, again, do you mean `SELECT`? If so, what's wrong with `GRANT SELECT ON...` Like the link I gave you demostrates?